# How can I extract a range of lines that matches pattern in a specific delimited file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file for example that contain delimited information with `;` as delimiter.

For example:

```
a;c;d;f;g;h;f
s;d;a;s;d;f;s
d;f;s;s;f;f;f
a;d;f;w;f;e;f
```

I want lines that for example has the 2nd delimited information is "d" OR the the 5th is "f" .

Can this be done by `sed`, `awk`, `grep` ?

Comment: @EdMorton: That was a result of huzeyfe's edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier in `awk` then in the other tools:

```
awk -F\; '$2 == "d" || $5 == "f"'
```

- `-F` sets the field separator.
- `||` represents the "or".